# Application more than one account?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm using the class TwitterOAuth Abrahams. You can connect one application more than one account? I myself have several accounts and want to connect simultaneously to all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using that library (or any other oauth implementation) you will have the user authorize your application, then build a client using those credentials.  You can store the credentials for each user who authenticates your application, and use the client with those credentials to make requests to the API on behalf of the user.

That library seems to have a great set of documentation, so I encourage you to work through that to understand how this works.